# Controlling the indentation of the second line in a list

Tags: spacing, lists, indentation, enumitem

I'm using enumitem to label text, and I'd like the text to all be aligned to the same indent as the first line in the list.  The second line begins underneath the label.  I'm sure there's a simple fix, but after reading the enumitem documentation I couldn't find anything.

```
\documentclass[multi={minipage}, border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{500bp}
\fontsize{20}{24}
\selectfont
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),align=left,topsep=1ex,parsep=0ex,itemsep=1ex,leftmargin=3ex]
\item{This is some long text that will overset to the second line of the list.  I would like the second line to be in line with the first.}
\item{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Please let me know if there's anything I should add to my mwe.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Got it, will do in the future.

Comment: What about omitting `align=left` and increasing `leftmargin` a bit?

Comment: I've been including align=left because I was finding that the label (D) was slightly wider than the others, and it was unaligned on the left with the rest of the labels.  I should mention I'm using Georgia font, which is presumably the source of the strange D.

Comment: Ok, have you tried `leftmargin=*` instead of `leftmargin=3ex`? (Together with `align=left`) Or will that mess with your layout?

Comment: Finally, if you need a `leftmargin` of 3ex, you can also use `align=parleft`, which creates a parbox for the label, and then manually increase `labelsep`.

Comment: Your suggestion of leftmargin=* worked perfectly.  If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 3.2 of the [`enumitem` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) explains the horizontal spacing of labels. Usually, `enumitem` would place the labels right aligned next to your 'item body', but as you pointed out, you would like to use left aligned labels with the `align=left` option for optical reasons.

In your case you can use `leftmargin=*`, which lets `enumitem` calculate an appropriate left margin, taking into account your `label` definition.

In case you want to explicitly set the left margin for your items, you can also use the `leftmargin=<dim>,labelsep=*` options instead, and `enumitem` will set the label separation length accordingly.